# Find multiple numbers in array

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I need to find multiple numbers contained in array, and randomly pick one.
This is my code:

```
 var get = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(json);
 var number = get.Where(r => r = 1).FirstOrDefault();

 if (number = 1)
 {
     //DO SOMETHING

 }
```

How do i randomly pick a number from an array list which is contained in the other array?

For example:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
array2 = [3, 4, 8, 10]
```

How do I check if numbers of array2 are contained inside array1 and randomly pick a number from the existing list only?

On the example, the check would give as result [4, 10] as 3 and 8 are not in array2, then I want to randomly pick either 4 or 10, which is contained inside the array1 and array2.

Those were just an example and not the actual numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use set intersect:

```cs
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 3, 4, 8, 10 };

var intersect = arr1.Intersect(arr2);
//intersect = {4, 10}
```

Now generate a random number between 0 and intersect.Count()

```
Random rand = new Random();
var randomIndex = rand.Next(intersect.Count());
```

Pick element at position randomIndex

```
var randomPick = intersect.ElementAt(randomIndex);
```

Comment: It works but the result is the same above, I get spammed in console "picked X number. picked X number. picked X number" over and over, about 30 times (see edited question)

Comment: Nevermind, the console was contained into a for loop. I missed a break; now it works. I'm accepting this answer as it's more clean and informative!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        var randomValue = array1
            .Where(x => array2.Contains(x))
            .OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid())
            .FirstOrDefault();
```